# Consume redis API in C#

Tags: c#, redis

I need to read following redis metrics

```
1.  Version 
2.  Uptime
3.  No of Jobs
4.  Overall Health
5.  Memory Stats (Allocated, Size in use)
6.  Latency Details
```

in ASP.Net MVC application.
My question is

1. how can consume radis API in MVC controller to get above metrics?
2. Is there any other way(best practice) to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the [StackExchange.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/) NuGet package?

Comment: No i haven't tried. because i have no idea how can do this. Could you please example how can i do this?

Comment: There you go [https://dzone.com/articles/install-nuget-packages-in-visual-studio](https://dzone.com/articles/install-nuget-packages-in-visual-studio)
You install the StackExchange.Redis package and then you can connect to a Redis Server using it's methods and read the desired properties

Comment: How to actually read those properties with that package I don't know since I never had the need to do this, but you should figure it out easily reading [their documentation](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read the redis metrics using StackExchange.Redis NuGet package in following way

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,allowAdmin=true");

        IServer server = redis.GetServer("localhost", {portnumber});
        var redisConfigurations = server.Info().ToList();
```